# When you extend a Java class in Clojure and define a method of the same name as one in that class, what is happening?

Tags: clojure, java-interop

I've been reading through Programming Clojure, and I've been having some trouble understanding Stuarts primary Java Interop example. He extends DefaultHandler, and creates a startElement method, and then passes that handler to an XML parser. What I don't understand, is what exactly is happening. Does his implementation of startElement override the one defined in DefaultHandler? I'm confused. I have no experience with Java, and little with object orientation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't own the book, but I found the [code](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/shcloj/source_code) and it looks like you're right. Here is the function (for others to see):

```
(def print-element-handler
  (proxy [DefaultHandler] [] 
   (startElement            
     [uri local qname atts] 
     (println (format "Saw element: %s" qname)))))
```

You're right about what it does. The proxy statement makes a new class, the equivilent of this Java code:

```
public class SomeNewClass extends DefaultHandler {
    public void startElement(String uri,
                     String localName,
                     String qName,
                     Attributes attributes) {
        System.out.println(*stuff*);
    }
}
```

So the proxy statement defines that class, and gives you an instance, which is now held in print-element-handler.

Comment: I picked your answer, because it's better than mine, and choosing my own answer just isn't fair. :)

Answer (score 1):

Glancing over the Java documentation for DefaultHandler answered my own question. http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html#startElement%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.xml.sax.Attributes%29

> By default, do nothing. Application writers may override this method in a subclass to take specific actions at the start of each element (such as allocating a new tree node or writing output to a file).